# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi programa lea únicamente la segunda línea de un archivo de texto en c++?

Tags: c++, archivo

Necesito que mi programa lea los números de la segunda línea de el archivo de texto pero únicamente esa!

Pongo el ejemplo de los números en el archivo:

```
10 20 30 50 //primera línea
5 4 2 //segunda línea
```

cómo puedo hacer para que mi código lea únicamente `5 4 2` que serían los números de la segunda línea?

El código que mostraré lee todos los números hasta que se llegue al final del archivo...

```
ifstream lectura;

lectura.open("archivo.txt", ios::in);

if (lectura.is_open()) {
    lectura >> nodo;
    while (!lectura.eof()) {
        lectura >> nodo;
        cout << nodo << endl;
    }
    lectura >> nodo;
}
else {
    cout << "Error! Archivo no existe " << endl;
}
lectura.close();
```

Comment: El especificador de nueva linea `\n` si no me equivoco es 10 en ascii... diviértete... :)

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi código lea únicamente [...] los números de la segunda línea?

No puedes.

---

La lectura de datos no funciona como tú crees: no existe el concepto de "primera línea" o "segunda línea"; simplemente existe un flujo de datos que se puede leer.

Lo más parecido a conseguir algo como lo que propones sería asumir que cada dato (línea) ocupa lo mismo y situar el puntero de lectura en el punto en que se supone que una línea determinada empezaría. Pero no es tu caso, tus líneas de datos tienen longitudes diferentes.

#### Propuesta.

Usa un contador para saber que has leído 2 líneas y lee mediante [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
if (std::ifstream lectura{"archivo.txt"}) {

    std::string nodo{};
    for (int linea = 0; linea != 2; ++linea)
        std::getline(lectura, nodo);
}
else {
    std::cout << "Error! Archivo no existe\n";
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Keg9dHl9QX6YEkFO)</kbd>.